# Sql server- join con función tabla

Tags: sql, servidor

Buenas tardes, quería saber si me podían ayudar con lo siguiente.

Tengo una función que hace una consulta al web service, es una función tabla. Se llama fosin.

También tengo una consulta que tiene una tabla de operaciones y uno de los campos es un número de expediente, ese número de expediente yo lo tengo que pasar como parámetro a la función fosin.

Lo que necesito también es hacer un join con esa función  y ahí es donde me hago el problema.

Espero que se entienda lo que quiero consultar. 
Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta e incluir lo que realmente que quieres, agregar el código "simulando" lo que buscas. Si es posible, agregar el resultado de tu consulta y el resultado esperado con el `JOIN` a la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo general cuando se usa una función que retorna un tipo tabla en una consulta se recomienda usar `APPLY`.

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fosin(@NRO_EXPEDIENTE VARCHAR(1))  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN 
   ( 
    SELECT 1 [ID], 'LETRA A' [DESCRIPCION] WHERE @NRO_EXPEDIENTE = 'A'
       UNION
    SELECT 2, 'LETRA B' WHERE @NRO_EXPEDIENTE = 'B'
       UNION
    SELECT 3, 'LETRA C' WHERE @NRO_EXPEDIENTE = 'C'       
   ) 
GO

CREATE TABLE OPERACION (
    ID INT,
    NRO_EXPEDIENTE VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO OPERACION VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D');


SELECT O.*, E.* 
FROM OPERACION O
CROSS APPLY dbo.fosin(NRO_EXPEDIENTE) E

SELECT O.*, E.*
FROM OPERACION O
OUTER APPLY dbo.fosin(NRO_EXPEDIENTE) E
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +----+----+----------------+------+-------------+
> |    | ID | NRO_EXPEDIENTE |  ID  | DESCRIPCION |
> +----+----+----------------+------+-------------+
> |  1 | 1  | A              | 1    | LETRA A     |
> |  2 | 2  | B              | 2    | LETRA B     |
> |  3 | 3  | C              | 3    | LETRA C     |
>
> +----+----+----------------+------+-------------+
> |    | ID | NRO_EXPEDIENTE |  ID  | DESCRIPCION |
> +----+----+----------------+------+-------------+
> |  1 |  1 | A              | 1    | LETRA A     |
> |  2 |  2 | B              | 2    | LETRA B     |
> |  3 |  3 | C              | 3    | LETRA C     |
> |  4 |  4 | D              | NULL | NULL        |
> +----+----+----------------+------+-------------+
> ```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/EDI62513)

---

**Referencia:**

- [Usar APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Muchas Gracias! me funciono! tuve que usar OUTER!

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias, con outer funciono a la perfeccion. Tengo otro problema, la funcion me devuelve el resultado como muestra la imagen. Yo necesito que el valor de las etiquetas sean columnas con el respectivo valor. lo intente hacer con pivot, pero la verdad es que no me salio. podras orientarme? Muchas Gracias

Comment: Sería bueno que realices una nueva pregunta, incluyendo también el intento que hiciste. Este sitio considera solo preguntas y respuestas, no se comporta como un foro. Podrías revisar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour