# pasar filas a columnas

Tags: sql, pivot

quería ver si me pueden ayudar en esto.

> Mi query es la siguiente:

```
   select 
   O.idgoOperacion [Operacion]
  ,uuu.Etiqueta
  ,uuu.Valor
   from Operacion O
```

---

docDocumentoArchivo Doa on doc.iddocDocumento = Doa.iddocDocumento
[dbo].ObtenerDatosPropios uuu **(Esta funcion pega en un web service)**

La consulta me devuelve lo que esta en la imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Yo necesito convertir en columnas las etiquetas** .

Lo intente hacer con **pivot** pero la verdad que no me funciono. 
Si alguien me puede orientar.. se lo agradezco!!

Answer (score 1):

Si el valor de las etiquetas ya lo tienes definidas podrías hacer:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
     SELECT ID, NOM_ETIQUETA, VALOR
     FROM ETIQUETA
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(    
     MAX(VALOR)
     FOR NOM_ETIQUETA IN ([A],[B],[C],[D],[E])
) AS PivotTable;
```

En caso las etiquetas sean dinámicas podrías considerar, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE ETIQUETA (
    ID INT,
    NOM_ETIQUETA VARCHAR(50),
    VALOR VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO ETIQUETA VALUES (1, 'A', 'VALOR A'), (1, 'B', 'VALOR B'), (1, 'C', 'VALOR C'), (1, 'D', 'VALOR D'), (1, 'E', 'VALOR E')

DECLARE @COLUMNAS VARCHAR(MAX), @SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLUMNAS = COALESCE(@COLUMNAS + ',', '') + '[' + NOM_ETIQUETA + ']'  FROM ETIQUETA

SELECT @SCRIPT = '
SELECT *
FROM
(
     SELECT ID, NOM_ETIQUETA, VALOR
     FROM ETIQUETA
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(    
     MAX(VALOR)
     FOR NOM_ETIQUETA IN (' + @COLUMNAS + ')
) AS PivotTable;'

EXEC(@SCRIPT);
```

Obtendrías:

> ```
> +----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
> | ID |    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |
> +----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
> |  1 | VALOR A | VALOR B | VALOR C | VALOR D | VALOR E |
> +----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
> ```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/ZXRI22326)

Comment: Una buena respuesta, lo que no está de más aclarar es que hay límites para el crecimiento "horizontal", tanto en la cantidad de columnas como en el tamaño de `@SCRIPT`, sería bueno que el OP indicara el motor para determinar dichos límites. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho hablas del famoso `The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements`. Esta pregunta viene de la respuesta a la pregunta [Sql server- join con función tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130219/sql-server-join-con-función-tabla#answer-130457) No se si es de gran calidad la pregunta, en caso prefieras puedes editarla o crear una nueva respuesta detallando tus recomendaciones. Saludos

Comment: Si efectivamente hablaba de eso, y en mucho menor medida el límite dado por `@SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX)`, que en el caso de SQLServer si mal no recuerdo es de algo más de 2Gb asi  que casi que lo podemos obviar. No sé como es en otros motores. Veamos si el OP actualiza la etiqueta del motor para eventualmente agregar esta info. Saludos.